# execute function right after xmlhttp.open and xmlhttp.send finished

Tags: javascript

I'm using this function in onclick:

```
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","reseller.php?ostan="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    get_lat_lon()
  }
}
```

I need to call get_lat_lon() function right after previous works done, but get_lat_lon() starts it self before previous jobs complete.

I need to call get_lat_lon() without delay when I set 1s delay it works correctly.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
xmlhttp.open
```

and

```
xmlhttp.send
```

executed before my get_lat_lon() function,

question is how can I force my `showUser()` function to execute `get_lat_lon()` function after `open` and `send` finished?

Comment: just move it inside `onreadystatechange`

Comment: Your php has nothing to do with this. The problem is that AJAX call (as the first 'A' in AJAX implies) are asynchronous, so when you call `get_fb()` in your code, it's almost impossible for the AJAX call to have returned already. EDIT: I was responding to OP's comment about the presence of the `php` tag.

Comment: moving get_fb to onreadystatechange is not working

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi: Define "not working".  If you want to perform some action after an asynchronous operation completes, that's exactly how you'd do it.

Comment: @AlirezaSabahi: Your recent edit still has the exact same problem as the original question.  You're trying to invoke an operation *immediately* instead of in response to the asynchronous operation.  Just move `get_fb();` to where you want to execute it.  In this case it would be in `onreadystatechange` immediately after updating the page with `responseText`.

Comment: @David thanks , fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         get_fb();//  THIS
      }
   };
```

Comment: try calling "xmlhttp.open" before "xmlhttp.onreadystatechange"

Comment: I edited my answer moving the function call to the end after adding the response html code.Try it now.

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript implements an `async function` declaration. What you'd be looking for is something like this:

```
function showUser(user)
{
    // your logic
    get_fb_async();
}

async function get_fb_async()
{
    get_fb() = await showUser(user);
}
```

This will have to vary according to how your `get_fb()` function behaves, but now you have the logic.

Further details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work